# spark.readstream option availableNow, process data landing during the streaming time?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, triggers, stream

According to the documentation https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#triggers The availableNow mode should process all data currently available, in a micro-batch style. My question is about the data that arrives meanwhile that the stream is processing the already existing data. Are the newly arriving data processed as well?
I did not find this case in the documentation. My code is like:

```
bronze_query = (spark.readStream
                     .format("cloudFiles")
                     .option("cloudFiles.format", "json")
                     .schema(schema)
                     .load(<some_path>)
                     .writeStream
                     .format("delta")
                     .outputMode("append")
                     .trigger(availableNow=True)
                     .trigger(processingTime='5 seconds')
                     .option("checkpointLocation", f"<path>")
                     .table("bronze"))
```

but concurrent to this code that is running, after the stream is initialized, in another databricks' notebook, I put another file to the loading path specified above. So the new file lands while the stream is on.